# Is SQL Server Naming trailing space insensitive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Location table in my OLTP which, while coding SSIS against it, I found a LocationCode column name to have a trailing space in it.

```
Create Table Location
(
    [LocationId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1)
    [LocationCode ] INT
)
```

Note that LocationCode column name has a trailing space.

And yet, the following code works.

```
SELECT LocationCode
From Location
```

As a matter of fact, we located several places where the trailing space is used in stored procs, and it has continued to work.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @Matt Rogish said, a trailing space in a column name is not treated like any other special character. It is actually ignored when parsing queries (whereas a hyphen or a tilda would not be ignored).

I have [submitted a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=483389) to Microsoft Connect for SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

> If delimited identifiers are used when
>   naming an object and the object name
>   contains trailing spaces, SQL Server
>   stores the name without the trailing
>   spaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28SQL.90%29.aspx

p.s. Delimited identifiers everywhere is a code smell -- they should be used SPARINGLY, not for every identifier.

Comment: @Matt: In SSMS, I rightclicked the table name and did "Script Create To New Window" - it came up with [LocationCode ] with a trailing space.

Comment: Feel free to remove the delimiters then if they're being auto-generated for identifiers that follow standard naming rules. Otherwise, it just adds noise :D

Comment: (It's probably a bug in SSMS)

Comment: @MattRogish: Try creating the table that I showed, and then script it out of SSMS.. the trailing space is retained. But you can query it without the trailing space.

Comment: Indeed, inside syscolumns it includes the trailing space (do select 'start' + name + 'end' from sysobjects where name like 'LocationCode%') however the interpreter must strip out the trailing spaces. So, it stores the space but ignores it upon query (as it probably ought to). Sounds like we found a documentation bug :D

Comment: Yes sir, I submitted it as a bug here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=483389